# Memory addresses in the system.map and vmlinux.o (after building Linux kernel), Do they correspond to each other?

Tags: linux-kernel, binaryfiles, disassembly

Do memory addresses in system.map and vmlinux.o correspond to each other? 
For example, Here is a part of the system.map file

```
c03011ec T handle_fiq_as_nmi
c0301270 T do_IPI
c0301274 T do_DataAbort
c0301328 T do_PrefetchAbort
```

And here is a part of the disassembled file for vmlinux.o.

```
000001ec <handle_fiq_as_nmi>:
 1ec:   e92d4038    push    {r3, r4, r5, lr}
 1f0:   e3004000    movw    r4, #0
 1f4:   ee1d3f90    mrc 15, 0, r3, cr13, cr0, {4}
 1f8:   e3404000    movt    r4, #0
 1fc:   e7935004    ldr r5, [r3, r4]
```

Why there are two different addresses for handle_fiq_as_nmi?

Comment: Because of relocation during actual loading? :-)

Comment: In this case vmlinux.o is not loaded. I'm just disassembling the created binary.

Comment: You can tag your question with more popular tag like *linux*, *assembly* to get quicker answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vmlinux.o` is a **relocatable** file, not **executable** file.

Use `file vmlinux.o` to see its type, or more detailed `readelf -h vmlinux.o`

Relocatable files need to be linked together to produce a final executable ( like `a.out`, for your case it's `vmlinux` ).

The address in a relocatable file is not the final address, they will be relocated during linking. See [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). The addresses in `System.map` are the final one.